# Why is my PyroCMS not building the view I tell it to?

Tags: pyrocms

Here is my controller code:

```
    $this->template
        ->set_breadcrumb( 'my stuff )
        ->set('questions', $questions)
        ->set('categories', $categories)
        ->build('index');
```

However, it doesn't seem to actually build the `index` view. It's building my `default.html` view in my theme.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have default.html as a view.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this question or the accepted answer. It will always build the default.html because that is the default layout.

The contents of the `index` go into `{{ template:body }}` which you should be echoed out in your layout of choice.